# Having openlayers load data from layer with visible = false

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

I have a Vector Layer with a Vector Source that is very expensive to load, but not so expensive to render. I have a button im my GUI to toggle the visibility of the layer.
The problem is, the first time the visibility is set to true, the loading takes a long time.
I would like to load the data for the layer in advance while the rest of the data is loaded (from all the visible layers), so that when the visibility is set to true, it only has to render it.
Is that possible in Openlayers?

I tried various stuff like setting the visibility to true on 'precompose' and then setting it to false after the HTTP request has been sent (with a custom 'loadend' event), but I couldn't get it to work properly; I couldn't switch the layer off anymore. I guess that happened because after the first time loading, it had the data cached, so my custom 'loadend' event didn't fire anymore.
Anyway I would favour a more elegant solution.

Edit:
I can't just send the request beforehand as in [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10118270/mike)s answer, because there is not **the** request. The request depends on the extent as well as the projection and thus is made in the `loader` function of the Vector Source.

Comment: just a shot into the dark but have you tried changing the layer order, so the vector layer is behind your map? Instead of the visibility the button could change the layer order again

Comment: That sounds like a nice trick! I'll give it a try, thx!

Comment: @Rob It worked like a charm. Thanks mate! If you're gonna write that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your layer to be loaded on the fly you have to make it visible, otherwise requests are not send. 
One way to have it work is to make the layer visible but prevent features drawing (return an empty style in your style function)

```js
var visible = false; // turn it to true to have the features drawn
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    // your source definition
  }),
  visible: true,
  style: function(feature, resolution) {
    if (!visible) {
      return [];
    } else {
      return your_style_for_the_feature;
    }
  }
});
```

The layer will be loaded and drawn but nothing will be visible as the features are not drawn. Just set visible to true to return your style in the style function and make the them drawn.
You also have to tell the source it has to redraw using `changed` function:

```js
// Draw the layer
visible = true;
vector.getSource().changed();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That sounds reasonable. Actually I already solved it using zIndex as in [Bobs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56891126/having-openlayers-load-data-from-layer-with-visible-false#comment100334373_56891126). But in a case where the rendering takes a significant amount of time, your solution would be better, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If the data isn't going to change it can be preloaded when the layers are created.

This is an example without preloading.  Three data layers are made visible 5 seconds after opening the map.  Only then is the data requested from the urls specified in the vector sources and it can then be seen loading at different speeds as one of the layers must download a 40mb KML file.

```js
var raster_OSM = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source:  new ol.source.OSM() 
});

var resolutions = ol.tilegrid.createXYZ().getResolutions();

var style_Cnty = new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#3399CC',
        width: 1.25
    })
});

var vector_Cnty = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tanhe03/kml/master/gz_2010_us_050_00_500k.kml',
        format: new ol.format.KML({extractStyles: false})
    }),
    maxResolution: resolutions[3],
    style: function(feature, resolution) {
        var styles = [ style_Cnty ];
        if (resolution < resolutions[8]) {
            var geom = feature.getGeometry();
            styles.push(
                new ol.style.Style({
                    geometry: geom.getInteriorPoints ? geom.getInteriorPoints() : geom.getInteriorPoint(),
                    text: new ol.style.Text({
                        font: 'bold 16px sans-serif',
                        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                            color: '#3399CC'
                        }),
                        backgroundFill: new ol.style.Fill({
                            color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)'
                        }),                            
                        text: feature.get('Name')
                    })
                })
            )
        }
        return styles;
    },
    visible: false
});

var vector_State = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tanhe03/kml/master/gz_2010_us_040_00_500k.kml',
        format: new ol.format.KML({extractStyles: false})
    }),
    maxResolution: resolutions[1],
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'purple',
            width: 1.25
        }) 
    }),
    visible: false
});

var vector_US = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tanhe03/kml/master/gz_2010_us_outline_500k.kml',
        format: new ol.format.KML({extractStyles: false})
    }),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#3399CC',
            width: 1.25
        }) 
    }),
    visible: false
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster_OSM, vector_Cnty, vector_State, vector_US],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform([-96, 38], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: 4
  })
});

setTimeout(function(){
  vector_Cnty.setVisible(true);
  vector_State.setVisible(true);
  vector_US.setVisible(true);
}, 5000);
```

```css
html, body, .map {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

But in this example preloading of the data starts when the layers are created.  The urls are requested by XHR immediately, the responses are parsed and the features added to the sources.  When the layers are made visible after 5 seconds all three layers should already be loaded.

```js
var raster_OSM = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source:  new ol.source.OSM() 
});

var resolutions = ol.tilegrid.createXYZ().getResolutions();

var style_Cnty = new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#3399CC',
        width: 1.25
    })
});

var vector_Cnty = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.KML({extractStyles: false})
    }),
    maxResolution: resolutions[3],
    style: function(feature, resolution) {
        var styles = [ style_Cnty ];
        if (resolution < resolutions[8]) {
            var geom = feature.getGeometry();
            styles.push(
                new ol.style.Style({
                    geometry: geom.getInteriorPoints ? geom.getInteriorPoints() : geom.getInteriorPoint(),
                    text: new ol.style.Text({
                        font: 'bold 16px sans-serif',
                        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                            color: '#3399CC'
                        }),
                        backgroundFill: new ol.style.Fill({
                            color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)'
                        }),                            
                        text: feature.get('Name')
                    })
                })
            )
        }
        return styles;
    },
    visible: false
});

var vector_State = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.KML({extractStyles: false})
    }),
    maxResolution: resolutions[1],
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'purple',
            width: 1.25
        }) 
    }),
    visible: false
});

var vector_US = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.KML({extractStyles: false})
    }),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#3399CC',
            width: 1.25
        }) 
    }),
    visible: false
});

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tanhe03/kml/master/gz_2010_us_050_00_500k.kml');
xhr.onload = function() {
  var source = vector_Cnty.getSource();
  source.addFeatures(source.getFormat().readFeatures(this.responseText, {featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'})); 
}
xhr.send();

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tanhe03/kml/master/gz_2010_us_040_00_500k.kml');
xhr.onload = function() {
  var source = vector_State.getSource();
  source.addFeatures(source.getFormat().readFeatures(this.responseText, {featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'})); 
}
xhr.send();

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tanhe03/kml/master/gz_2010_us_outline_500k.kml');
xhr.onload = function() {
  var source = vector_US.getSource();
  source.addFeatures(source.getFormat().readFeatures(this.responseText, {featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'})); 
}
xhr.send();

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster_OSM, vector_Cnty, vector_State, vector_US],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform([-96, 38], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: 4
  })
});

setTimeout(function(){
  vector_Cnty.setVisible(true);
  vector_State.setVisible(true);
  vector_US.setVisible(true);
}, 5000);
```

```css
html, body, .map {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The problem with this solutions is, that my loading function depends on the extent. So when ever I scroll on the map, a new request has to be sent (with a different URL). For this reason the function that loads our data is registered as a `loader` of the Vector Source. I will edit the question with this info.

Comment: To be useful preloading would require you to preload the maximum extent (equivalent to using ol.loadingstrategy.all).  Otherwise you would still see delays due to data loading when you pan the map or zoom out, even if the layer is already visible.

Comment: That's right, but it would probably be too expensive again, since loading 60m x 60m already takes ca. 15 seconds and the whole extent is about 80 km x 80 km.
For that reason this layer is completely disabled when not zoomed in to 1:200 or lower. Even if the user turns it on, it won't load before 1:200.